# Switch image when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want the button image to be switched to another image when clicked, but it seems like the toggle class function does not work.

The check rating function checks if the thumbup function is clicked then return a variable true/false. I'm quite new to JS, it'll be great if anyone could help to simplify this function.

```js
var clickedThumbUP = false;
var clickedThumbDown = false;

// check if thumbup is clicked
function checkRating(clicks) {

  if (clicks === true) {
    console.log("rating is clicked")
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

function clickthumbUp() {

  // check if the button is clicked
  clickedThumbUP = true;
  var rating_up = checkRating(clickedThumbUP);

  if (rating_up === true) {
    $('#thumbup').attr('src', "https://via.placeholder.com/100/ff0000")

    // $("img", this).toggleClass("thumpup thumb-up-black");
  } else {
    $('#thumbup').attr('src', "https://via.placeholder.com/100/ff00ff")
  }

  return rating_up
}
```

```css
#thumb-up-black {
  background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/scl/fi/ufflmo9rk3oey45v04dlo/icons8-thumbs-up-50_b.png?rlkey=thmvs34cuo7fiw66wzkaj8o74&dl=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-img">
  <img id="thumbup" onclick="clickthumbUp();" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you "clicking" #thumbup in the function that's called when you clicked #thumbup? It'll recurse without a base case.

Comment: What is `checkRating()`? And what makes you think the `toggleClass` is the problem?

Comment: *$("i", this)*: you don't have any `<i>` tags in your html.

Comment: I've made some edits to the post

Comment: Although this isn't the only issue that you are having, `#thumb-up-black` isn't a class in CSS so you can't toggle it. You would need `.thumb-up-black`. But that isn't the only issue just one

Comment: I see the big issue, your CSS is trying to change the background image of an img tag. That isn't going to work the way you want it to. The better option is to use a button and toggle the background on that.

Comment: I made an edit and added the image link to the attribute, but it still doesnt toggle. I wanted to change the button image, not the background though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

Your CSS refers to `#thumb-up-black` but you are toggling it like a class.

Your CSS is trying to change the background image of an img tag.
And you are toggling `thumpup` but never mention that.

For my answer, I'm using a button instead of img so I can change its background via CSS. I can also use other elements but I prefer a button.

And I'm using jquery's event handler instead of an line click handler.

```js
const clickedThumbUP = true;

$(".rating-img button").click(function(){
  
  let rating_up = checkRating(clickedThumbUP);

  if (clickedThumbUP === true) {
    $(this).toggleClass("thumbup thumb-up-black");
  }  
});

// check if thumbup is clicked
function checkRating(clicks) {

  if (clicks === true) {
    console.log("rating is clicked")
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }

}
```

```css
.thumb-up-black {
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/scl/fi/ufflmo9rk3oey45v04dlo/icons8-thumbs-up-50_b.png?rlkey=thmvs34cuo7fiw66wzkaj8o74&dl=1);
}

.thumbup{
  background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/scl/fi/vbid7c77txd1eplkm1b6f/icons8-thumbs-up-50.png?rlkey=es8b13t6uc3cptkbn94kwdfic&dl=1);

  
}

.rating-img button{
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating-img">
  <button class="thumbup"></button>
</div>
```